# Printing data from fields that exist within a model onto an HTML page in Django

Tags: django, django-models

[image]

I am trying to print a field that exists within my model onto an HTML page in Django.

I want the street address field to print onto the page. The username prints onto the page within any issues. What's the best way to do this?

Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(max_length = 5)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add = False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.address

class Job(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    position = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    employer_address = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(max_length = 5)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = False)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add = False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 20, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.position
```

View:

```
def all(request):
    users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    return render_to_response('all.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

HTML:

```
{% extends 'home.html' %}

{% block content %}

<!-- user is being called from the variable we declared as users in the previous page -->

{% for user in users %}

<li>{{ user }}</li>

{% endfor %}



<!-- {% for address in user.street_address %}

<li>{{address}}</li>

{% endfor %} -->

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're looking to have all of the addresses after all of the users, put the second loop inside the first.

You're passing `users`, a collection of `User` objects to the template rendering. `User` doesn't have a `street_address` field - `Address` does. You'll need to pass `Address` objects to the form.

It also appears that `street_address` is just a `CharField`, not any sort of list.

If `user` had a `street_address` field, you could simply do:

```
{% for user in users %}
    <li>{{ user }}</li>
    <li>{{ user.street_address }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Since it doesn't, look instead into this:

```
def all(request):
    addresses = Address.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('all.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and

```
{% for address in addresses %}
    <li>{{ address.user }}</li>
    <li>{{ address.street_address }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: still doesn't seem to be printing the address information to the page.

Comment: Correct, I have added an image from the admin panel showing that that field is filled.

Comment: Very nice explanation! I'm starting to understand this now, but I'm getting an error. "Exception Value: 
global name 'Address' is not defined"

Comment: ahhhh got it! Just had to import from .models Thanks much!